# Replace document.all with document.getElementById with If Else Statement

Tags: getelementbyid

I am trying to rewrite this function to remove the document.all and replace with document.getElementById, but so far I am not having much luck. 
This is the original function:

```
if (document.all.DeptFundingYN.value == "TRUE") {
```

This is what I have:

```
function VoidRtn(fRecNum,fReferenceNum) {
  var DeptFundingYNField = document.getElementById("VoidID");

  if(DeptFundingYNField.value == "TRUE") {
    var href = "PaymentsEntry.asp?speedpay=false&CLAIM=YES&LevelCode=Void&Mode=Update&Reference_Num=" + document.PayClaimGridForm.ReferenceNum.value;
    href += "&RecNum=" + fRecNum;
    document.location.href = href;
  } else {
    alert("No Department Funding");
  }
}
```

This button:

```
<button title=""Void This Payment"" id=""VoidID"" class=""whitefontbutton"" onclick=""VoidRtn(" & fRecNum & "," & fReferenceNum & ");"" style=""width: 15px; height: 15px;BACKGROUND: #6a7dae; FONT-SIZE: 7 PT"" onmouseover=""this.style.background='#000066'"" onmouseout=""this.style.background='#6a7dae'"">V</button></font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why the double-quotes appear twice in your `<button>`, for example:

```
<button title=""Void This Payment"" ...
```

It should be:

```
<button title="Void This Payment" ...
```

And there is no `"TRUE"` value anywhere in your markup.
The only way your condition can work is if you add a `value="TRUE"` attribute to the button, for example:

```
<button title="Void This Payment" value="TRUE" ...
```

With these changes, it should work.